# Access nested api data (vue)

Tags: json, api, vue.js, nested

I have problems to access nested data from my api call. The JSON response looks like this:
[image]

I try to access the attribute_name in attributes. And the language_name in languages.
I can display the location_name with the following code  `{{ userdetails.location.location_name }}`

---

I have always problems with nested api data. Is there a guide how to access data from an api?

Thank you!

Update: My code looks like this

```
data() {
    return {
      userdetails: undefined,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    getUserData() {
      DataService.getUserById()
        .then((response) => {
          this.userdetails = response.data;
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(
            "Ein Fehler beim User ist aufgetreten: " + error.response
          );
        });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getUserData();
  },
};
```

Comment: The response is saved in any variable? I supose you save the `res.data` in `userdetails`?
Can you show us the code?

Comment: @MuXeD I added my code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attributes` property is array so try (`index` is index in array):

```
{{ userdetails.attributes[index].attribute_name }}
```

and if you want to show them all:

```
<div v-for="(attr, i) in userdetails.attributes" :key="i" >
  {{ attr.attribute_name }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to add another "attribute" but it works now perfectly. 

                  <div v-for="(attr, i) in userdetails.attributes" :key="i">
                    {{ attr.attribute.attribute_name }}
                  </div>

Comment: nice, cheers :)